# Add-BindingRedirect doesn't change App.config though it should

Tags: nuget, assemblybinding

I published nuget package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChessKit.ChessLogic/). It is basically one .net assembly witch

- references FSharp.Core 4.3.1
- references FParsec

  - that references FSharp.Core 4.0.0.0 (!)

All pretty straightforward.

Now when I add the package to a new VS2013 C# project, it doesn't add the  tag to the app.config, meaning it crashes at run-time with "Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0 ..." message.

If add add the  tag manually it works. Add-BindingRedirect command doesn't do anything either. Apparently it doesn't see the issue with FSharp.Core.

What am I doing wrong? Should I add a hint somewhere that the  tag for the FSharp.Core is needed?

NOTE: following the references you can [download](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChessKit.ChessLogic/) the *.nuspec file as well as find the [git repository](https://github.com/marhoily/ChessKitFs) and appveyor [build](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/marhoily/chesskitfs).